# Get the Username in a Gmail Contextual Gadget

Tags: javascript, jquery, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I am writing a Gmail Contextual Gadget, and in order to authenticate the user correctly on the server, i need to know their full email address (john@googleapps.com).

I can retrieve the domain (googleapps.com) but not the username.

Using the content extractors I can get the 'To' field on the email, the only problem is if there are two users on the same domain emailed (ie john@googleapps.com and james@googleapps.com).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement SSO (single sign-on) within the contextual gadget. When the contextual gadget loads it passes the opensocialid of the user. You have to maintain a correlation between the user emailid and user opensocialid in your local database and do the identification by opensocialid lookup.

Read here for more details: http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/best_practices.html#gadget_sso

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of accuracy, I think that Nands's response may no longer be correct due to a change in google's policies.

The latest Gmail Contextual Gadget doco (https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/basic) suggests that OAuth gadget's are no longer supported.

I'd love to be proven wrong on this.

Comment: I don't have anything I'm working on currently to check whether these changes have an effect, as I can't test it and verify, I won't change the marked answer. But thanks for the update!